# Is there a way to extend Bootstrap classes in SCSS without having to import Bootstrap itself?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following custom class defined in a `sample.scss` file.

```
.custom-class {
    @extend .rounded-pill;
    @extend .border;
    @extend .bg-light;
}
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error

> messageOriginal: The target selector was not found. Use "@extend .rounded-pill !optional" to avoid this error

Changing it to `@extend .rounded-pill !optional` make the error goes away. However, the `.rounded-pill`, `.border` and `.bg-light` are not imported/applied to the `custom-class` as desired. Is there a way to extend bootstrap CSS classes without having to import bootstrap classes directly into my project?

The idea is to include bootstrap's CDS and define my own classes that extend bootstrap.

If I add `@import ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` everything works, but bootstrap code is imported into my files which I do not want.

**UPDATED**

For clarifications, here is an example of what I would like to accomplish,

I have the following code in `custom-close.scss` file. when compiled, the following SCSS code should result into a new CSS file called `custom-close.css`.

```
@import ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_close';
@import ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons';

.custom-close {
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-close;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As you can see, I am importing the `_close.scss` and `_buttons.scss` files from the Bootstrap module.

But, importing the `_close` and the `_buttons` causes ALL the code found in `_buttons` and `_close` files to be included into the final file (i.e, `custom.css`).

Comment: This is possible (and would work exactly as you have it written) if you can find a build of Bootstrap that uses [Sass placeholder selectors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors/) instead of classes. Here's a related github issue where a user requested this from bootstrap but it was closed:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30926

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `@extend` something without importing it.

Not sure what you mean by *"bootstrap code is imported into my files which I do not want"*, but I can assure you there's no downside to it. In fact, whenever you're importing Bootstrap's CSS, whether pre-compiled or as SCSS, you're *"importing Bootstrap's code into your files"*.

Here's the official documentation on [how to customise Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/).

To override any defaults, define their values before importing them from Bootstrap.

To use Bootstrap @mixins, you have to import them from Bootstrap. There's no other way.
What you're asking for is the equivalent of wanting to use a package in your code without importing it.

---

Upon further clarifications, it seems that by *"bootstrap code is imported into my files"* you meant *"bootstrap code is included into my build"*. To exclude any dependency from your package, declare that dependency as `external`. Each build tool (`rollup`, `webpack`, `vite`) has its own specific syntax around it. They're fairly similar.

To let a project consuming your package know it needs a particular other package in order for yours to work, you have to also declare that dependency in `peerDependencies` of your `package.json`. This will auto-generate a warning in console for any project installing your package which doesn't have a compatible version of your peer dependencies installed in their project.

---

As a side-note, you [should change](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/) your imports to:

```scss
@use 'bootstrap/...'
```

Comment: by `bootstrap code is imported into my files which I do not want`, I am trying to avoid having to import ALL bootstrap classes into my compiled file. In other words, I want to be able to compile my scss file and generate my own css file `my-custom.css`. The end result I want to include the bootstrap's CDN, then `my-custom.css` file. The `my-custom.css` file should not include everything the CDN has. Is there a way to reference the bootstrap into my SCSS file so that the compiler is able to generate my classes by applying the `@extend` but not include bootstrap code in the final css file?

Comment: I updated the question with some clarifications.